# randomly display circles inside of box

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to randomly display a few circles inside a box. None of those circles should be outside the box or even touch the corner of the box. Is there a way to plot all circles inside the div with relative values (percent)? I would like to able to say for instance: Plot this circle in 10% distance relative to the left side of the box and 40% distance from the top of the box. The positions should be relative to the box. At the moment, percent values are chosen with regard to the whole page but not just the div (the box).

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="triangle.css">

<body align = "center">

    <div id='area' align = "center" 
style="width:90vw; height:40vw; border: 2px solid; margin-top:2%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">        
    </div>
```

Javascript function:

```
for(var i=0; i<10;i++){
        Left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 80)+10;
        Top = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) +5;
        $("#area").append("<div class='circle-blue' + id=" + i + "></div>");
        $("#" +i).css({"position":"absolute","top": Top + "%", "left": Left + "%"});
  };
```

Here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/p6NE3/13/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the below to your CSS:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/p6NE3/16/)

```
#area{
    position:relative;
}
```

You need to set `position:relative` for `#area` so the circles have a marker to base their positioning *relative* to.

Comment: thanks for the hint, I didn't set position:relative for #area, too.

Comment: what do you think about using canvas? It might be a better way. But even then, I would have to figure out how to avoid collision (achieve that no circles are touching the border)

Answer (score 0):

You could easily accomplish this the way you are doing it, just give the box or div a set padding to make sure that the circles will always be inside. Also don't make the max width or height of all circles bigger than the div your putting them in. Also instead of .Append, do .HTML, this will place your new element inside, and it tends to work better.